# Application startup page unknown view in Android

Tags: android

When I running application in mobile, it was show a blank page by the my app name on Actionbar, and after a second it was navigating to my MainActivity.
I was set in manifest

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />             
 </intent-filter>
```

but not help, I was try

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.home" />             
 </intent-filter>
```

but not help.
How to set my application startup page to run at first time?

Comment: Are you using ActionBar Sherlock?

Comment: No, I am using custom ActionBar

Answer (score 0):

May be you are doing some costly operations in onCreate. If that is the case then do the tasks in another thread . Do like this

```
onCreate(Bundle b){
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.id.something);
    // now use different thread or handler to do costly things
}
```

Comment: I think this is not really true. Actually setContentView will not be dispatched. If this is true, then a black screen (hanging) would appear before the activity shows.

Comment: i thought he is talking about that blank screen @SherifelKhatib

Comment: mmm I think it is related to ActionBar Sherlock on old devices. Not sure though

Comment: How I was understand device was drawing the first its default Activity and then setting it to your configuration, for excample if onCreate method I am writing getActionBar().hide(), then run application, then it was showing an ActionBar for a second and then hide it, but I don`t want to show it. I know that I can disable actionbar form manifest, but it was show how work my activity in real.